# Does Aurelia have an AngularJS $watch alternative?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, aurelia

I'm trying to migrate my current Angular.js project to Aurelia.js.
I'm trying to do something like that:

**report.js**

```
export class Report {
       list = [];

       //TODO
       listChanged(newList, oldList){
             enter code here
       }
}
```

**report.html**

```
<template>
    <require from="component"></require>
    <component list.bind="list"></component>
</template>
```

So the question is: how to detect when is the list changed?

In Angular.js I can do

```
$scope.$watchCollection('list', (newVal, oldVal)=>{ my code });
```

Maybe Aurelia have something similar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For `@bindable` fields the `listChanged(newValue, oldValue)` would be called whenever the `list` value is updated. Please take a look [Aurelia docs](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#template-controllers)

```
@customAttribute('if')
@templateController
export class If {
  constructor(viewFactory, viewSlot){
    //
  }

  valueChanged(newValue, oldValue){
    //
  }
}
```

You can also use `ObserveLocator` as described in Aurelia author's blogpost [here](http://blog.durandal.io/2015/04/03/aurelia-adaptive-binding/#usingtheobserverlocator):

```
import {ObserverLocator} from 'aurelia-binding';  // or 'aurelia-framework'

@inject(ObserverLocator)
class Foo {  
  constructor(observerLocator) {
    // the property we'll observe:
    this.bar = 'baz';

    // subscribe to the "bar" property's changes:
    var subscription = this.observerLocator
      .getObserver(this, 'bar')
      .subscribe(this.onChange);
  }

  onChange(newValue, oldValue) {
    alert(`bar changed from ${oldValue} to ${newValue}`);
  }
}
```

## UPD

As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28437456/2044039) by Jeremy Danyow:

> The ObserverLocator is Aurelia's internal "bare metal" API. There's now a public API for the binding engine that could be used:

```
import {BindingEngine} from 'aurelia-binding'; // or from 'aurelia-framework'

@inject(BindingEngine)
export class ViewModel {
  constructor(bindingEngine) {
    this.obj = { foo: 'bar' };

    // subscribe
    let subscription = bindingEngine.propertyObserver(this.obj, 'foo')
      .subscribe((newValue, oldValue) => console.log(newValue));

    // unsubscribe
    subscription.dispose();
  }
}
```

Best regards, Alexander

Comment: don't you know solution with custom events?

Answer (score 7):

## Your original code will work with one small tweak:

**report.js**

```js
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework'; // or 'aurelia-binding'

export class Report {
       @bindable list;  // decorate the list property with "bindable"

       // Aurelia will call this automatically
       listChanged(newList, oldList){
             enter code here
       }
}
```

**report.html**

```html
<template>
    <require from="component"></require>
    <component list.bind="list"></component>
</template>
```

*Aurelia has a convention that will look for a `[propertyName]Changed` method on your viewmodel and call it automatically.  This convention is used with all properties decorated with `@bindable`.  More info [here](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#custom-elements)*

Answer (score 1):

It seems better solution for current case is **[CustomeEvent](https://davidwalsh.name/customevent)**

So complete solution would look like that

**report.html**

```
<template>
    <require from="component"></require>
    <component list.bind="list" change.trigger="listChanged($event)"></component>
</template>
```

**component.js**

```
@inject(Element)
export class ComponentCustomElement {
    @bindable list = [];

    //TODO invoke when you change the list
    listArrayChanged() {
        let e = new CustomEvent('change', {
            detail: this.lis
        });

        this.element.dispatchEvent(e);
    }
}
```

You have to change component element, add some trigger function that sand you change event. I suppose that component knows when list changed.