# Get access to Aurelia's Dependency Injection system without constructor injection

Tags: javascript, aurelia, aurelia-di

Is there a way to get access to Aurelia's Dependency Injection system without constructor injection.

I have a class called `Box`.  I need to know when one of its properties change so I can update my validation.  I found that I can use `bindingEngine.propertyObserver` from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28437456/16241).

But my instances of `Box` are created by `BreezeJs`, not Aurelia.  So using `@inject` (or `@autoinject` in my case) to get the instance of `bindingEngine` is not going to work.

I saw `aurelia.container.get` will let me resolve from Aurelia's DI framework.  But that needs the current instance of the `Aurelia` object.  The only way I can see to get that is... constructor injection!

So, to get around constructor injection, you need... constructor injection!

I hope I am missing something and there is another way to get an instance of `bindingEngine` without constructor injection.

NOTE: For now I will just convert my variable in to a javascript property and fire an changed event on my own.  But I know that this is going to move me to dirty checking...  :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to know when a breeze entity's properties change, use the `entityAspect.propertyChanged` event:

> http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/api-docs/classes/EntityAspect.html#event_propertyChanged
>
> ```js
> order.entityAspect.propertyChanged.subscribe(
> function (propertyChangedArgs) {
>     // this code will be executed anytime a property value changes on the 'order' entity.
>     var entity = propertyChangedArgs.entity; // Note: entity === order
>     var propertyNameChanged = propertyChangedArgs.propertyName;
>     var oldValue = propertyChangedArgs.oldValue;
>     var newValue = propertyChangedArgs.newValue;
> });
> ```

Circumventing constructor injection is not recommended.  It violates the [dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), however there is a mechanism for doing so:

**main.js**

```js
export function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.container.makeGlobal();
  ...
}
```

**box.js**

```js
import {Container} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';

let bindingEngine = Container.instance.get(BindingEngine);
```

Comment: Thank you!  You are right about using breeze's change notification.  (I was just so into Aurelia's system, I forgot.  Thanks again!

Comment: Is it bad to use the `BindingEngine` instead of breeze's system?  I wired up the binding engine and it worked great.  I think I prefer the `BindingEngine` personally, but if there a a reason breeze's system I would like to know it.

Comment: If you're using aurelia-breeze, the binding system is using the breeze system, so ultimately you are indirectly using the breeze system.  I would go with the native breeze system.  It avoids the bad pattern of circumventing constructor injection.

Comment: @JeremyDanyow I tried this with `aurelia-dependency-injection@1.3.1` and it works now without `aurelia.container.makeGlobal();`. Is it intended behavior?