# aurelia observerlocator onchange does not find variables

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have the following code, but when the onChange is triggered it gives me an error. (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'myVar' of undefined)

```
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { ObserverLocator } from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(ObserverLocator)
export class myClass{
    field= "";
    myVar = 0;
    constructor(observerLocator) {
        this.field= "";
        var subscription = observerLocator
                .getObserver(this, 'field')
                .subscribe(this.onChange);

    }

    onChange(){
        this.myVar +=1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Remove `this` from `this.myVar = 0;` then it should work

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sorry I did a mistake when i created the demonstration code. I get this error(Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'myVar' of undefined) when i change the value of field.

Comment: Try to use the BindingEngine instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28419242/property-change-subscription-with-aurelia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's scope issue, just try

```
var subscription = observerLocator
            .getObserver(this, 'field')
            .subscribe(this.onChange.bind(this));
```